# Can you find who I am?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, english

> I look like a boat does from above
>
> I'm sensitive
>
> I'm often painted around the edges
>
> I'm likely to be beaten in a fight
>
> My name is used by a company to revolutionize their industry
>
> Make me wet and I'll never see you again

I'm new to this and would appreciate feedback.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Partial answer: Is it

> An eye?

I look like boat's top view

> Has the same shape

I am sensitive

> Self explanatory

I was often painted around the edges

> Eyeshadow, kohl and other eye makeup

I am the one who gets beaten most probably on a fight

> Black eyes are common in fights

My name is used by a company to revolutionize their industry

> Used by Apple for IPhones and IPads

Make me wet and i will never see you again

> Teary eyes make it difficult to see

Comment: I phone, I pad, I XXXX

Comment: It is exactly the right answer. You have predicted it in just 5 minutes? You are awesome.

Answer (score 9):

Are you a

> Window

Explanation follows

I look like boat's top view

> a normal boat will look like a window with straight grills in top view

I am sensitive

> Glass windows will get shattered easily (with stone or something hard)

I was often painted around the edges

> Window borders are usually painted. Not the glass part.

I am the one who gets beaten most probably on a fight

> Car/house or store windows are beaten by mobs usually.

My name is used by a company to revolutionize their industry

> Microsoft Windows

Make me wet and i will never see you again

> Wet windows will be more opaque.

Comment: Sorry friend. But you got a great imagination. I wish the answer was WINDOW, +1 for the effort.

Comment: Obligatory joke: https://cdn.drawception.com/images/panels/2015/10-3/Zr5AKbLaOO-2.png

Answer (score 1):

Are you a

> Shield

I look like a boat does from above

> Shields can take the shape of a boat

I'm sensitive

> Shields can be broken (Doesn't quite fit)

I'm often painted around the edges

> Shields are painted

I'm likely to be beaten in a fight

> Shields will get hit in a fight

My name is used by a company to revolutionize their industry

> Lots of anti virus software include shield in their name

Make me wet and I'll never see you again

> Not sure on this one

Comment: That was a great answer. Doenst quite fit the second and last answer . +1 for the amazing effort.